# Show that there exists a number $r$ with $0<r<1$ such that $0<x_n<r^n$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: limits

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim(x_{n+1}/x_n)=L<1$. Show that there exists a number $r$ with $0<r<1$ such that $0<x_n<r^n$ for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb N$.

I know that I can set a $c$ such that $L<c<1$ and try to express $r$ by $c$, but I don't know what is this about exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Step 1. Show there is $c, r_1$ so that $x_n<c r_1^n$ for large $n$.

Step 2. For $r>r_1$, $x_n<(c^{1/n}r_1)^n<r^n$ for large $n$, since $c^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Can you please explain clearer about step 2?

Comment: @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ Since $c^{1/n}\to 1$ and $r/r_1>1$, $c^{1/n}<r/r_1$ for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $x_1=1$. Choose $N$ such that $|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-L|<\frac{1-L}{2}=\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<\epsilon + L=r_1<1$ holds for all $n>N$. Now, $x_k=\frac{x_k}{x_{k-1}}\cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{x_3}{x_2}\cdot \frac{x_2}{x_1}$, for all $k$. Let $M=\frac{x_N}{x_{N-1}}\cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{x_2}{x_1}$, and so: $x_n=\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}\cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{x_{N+1}}{x_N}\cdot M$, for all $n>N$. Thus $x_n < r_1^{n-N}M$ for all $n>N$. This is not quite yet the expression you want, but now all you have to show is that you can adjust $r_1$ a bit to improve to: $x_n<r_2^nM$ and then improve a bit further to obtain the expression you want.

Comment: How can you be so sure that $ϵ+L>0$?

Comment: it's the sum of two positive numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I mean How can you be so sure that $ϵ+L＜1$?

Comment: $\epsilon+L=\frac{1+L}{2}$ and $L<1$.